# How to make Mathematica Simplify?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Let us define

```
r1 = 1;r2 = 2;
```

and

```
beta2[t_] := {r1*Cos[2*Pi*t], r2*Sin[2*Pi*t]}
beta1[t_] := beta2[t + 4.8*t^2*(t - 1)^2] 
k[v_] := If[Norm[v] > 0, v/Sqrt[Norm[v]], 0]
```

with

```
q2[t_] :=  FunctionExpand[k[beta2'[t]], Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals]

q1[t_] :=  FunctionExpand[k[beta1'[t]], Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals]
```

Now when I call

```
 q1'[3]
```

I get

{4.56985 + 
  0.157049 (10.2293 Derivative[1][Abs][-5.97566] - 
     40.9174 Derivative[1][Abs][-3.88322]), -28.1291 + 
  0.102057 (10.2293 Derivative[1][Abs][-5.97566] - 
     40.9174 Derivative[1][Abs][-3.88322])}

**Question**

> How to simplify this expression?

Comment: Apply `FunctionExpand` to the final expression to simplify it.  Sorry, I didn't follow the rest of the code ...

Comment: You can't take derivative with respect to a number. so not sure what `q1'[3]` is meant to represent. Also, `If[Norm[v] > 0, v/Sqrt[Norm[v]], 0]` return the result you show, since it is passed a symbolic expression.  You are mixing symbolic with numerical computation in strange way.

Answer (score 6):

Generally speaking, [`If`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html) is for programming and [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) is for function construction. While the distinction is somewhat artificial, the significant difference is that `Piecewise`, although having the attribute `HoldAll`, evaluates its arguments.  The effective difference can been seen by evaluating `q1[t]` with the OP's definition of `k[v]` and this one:

```
k[v_] := Piecewise[{{v/Sqrt[Norm[v]], Norm[v] > 0}}]
```

With this definition, `FunctionExpand` works properly to expand the instances of `Abs` that show up when `Norm` is evaluated.  The OP's test example works properly with this change:

```
q1'[3]
(*  {-46106.6, 122826.}  *)
```